# What VSCode extensions are there for working with block themes?

Tags: theme-development, block-editor, syntax-highlighting

I recently took another dive into Wordpress block themes by looking at the TwentyTwentyTwo theme. I'm noticing that all templating seems to take place either in PHP strings or HTML files chalked full of ugly HTML comments.

[image]
[image]

I'm not seeing any tools out there for syntax highlighting and/or formatting for block themes.

Are WP block theme developers just developing themes in strings and html comments or am I missing something?

Comment: *Are WP block theme developers just developing themes in strings and html comments or am I missing something?*

If you're writing strictly in code and not using the Graphical interface, than those HTML -like comments are attributes and supports and a fundamental part of the block editor and full-site editing themes. https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/block-grammar-basics/ has a good background on the basics on them.

Answer (score 2):

It's missing some very new blocks (for example templates, template parts), but there is the [autocompleter for block grammar](https://fullsiteediting.com/vs-code-autocomplete-for-block-grammar/).